# Receive text (or csv) via post with Flask and read it in text/string mode (non binary)

Tags: python, csv, flask, google-cloud-platform

I'm receiving text files in Flask with method Post. The problem is that when I read these files with the stream reader, readlines() or read() I have all the binary code that I don't need.

Since I'm working with Google Cloud Functions I want to avoid saving the file but in the worst case could be a solution.

```
@app.route("/decode", methods=['POST'])
def receive():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        file = request.files['file']

        dialect = sniffer.sniff(
            str(file.readlines())
        )
```

The example of line that I receive with readlines() is:
`b'1238124124Product Text  001\n',` 
Any solution? I need to work with lines as string because I need to discover if the file is a CSV, a positional one or a mix of both.

I've tried with file.read().decode('utf-8') but didn't worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert the file from binary to text I recommend using [`io.TextIOWrapper`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper). The lines are then available as `str`.

```py
import io

@app.post('/decode')
def receive():
    file = request.files.get('file')
    if file: 
        with io.TextIOWrapper(file) as fh:
            lines = fh.readlines()
            print(lines)
    # ...
```